# A linear system of equations $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ has two different solutions $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{v}$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

A linear system of equations $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ has two different solutions $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{v}$.
1. Show that $\frac{1}{3}\mathbf{u}+\frac{2}{3}\mathbf{v}$ is also a linear solution of the linear system.
So we do $\frac{1}{3}\mathbf{u}+\frac{2}{3}\mathbf{v} = \frac{1}{3}\mathbf{x}+\frac{2}{3}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}$. What next? Is it $A(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{0}$? Thanks!

Comment: by linearity, $A\left(\dfrac13\mathbf u+\dfrac23\mathbf v\right)=\dfrac13A\mathbf u+\dfrac23A\mathbf v$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. We do$$A\left(\frac13\mathbf u+\frac23\mathbf v\right)=\frac13(A\mathbf u)+\frac23(A\mathbf v)=\frac13\mathbf b+\frac23\mathbf b=\mathbf b.$$

Comment: Yes of course use linearity thank you very much!!!

Comment: How could I show that this system has infinitely many solutions?

Comment: For each $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, $A\bigl(\lambda\mathbf u+(1-\lambda)\mathbf v\bigr)=\mathbf b$, by the same argument as the one that I used in my answer.

Comment: Right thank you so much. Suppose that $\lambda\mathbf{u}+(1-\lambda)\mathbf{v}$ is a solution to this system, where $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ then use the linearity argument.

Comment: I have a final question. With all this being considered why would the null space of $A$ have dimension at least one?

Comment: Because $\operatorname{null}A\neq\{0\}$ and therefore $\dim\operatorname{null}A\geqslant1$. The space $\{0\}$ is the only space whose dimension is $0$.

Comment: Why did you unmark my answer as the accepted one? Did you find a mistake in it?

Comment: No I must have clicked it on accident sorry! Could you elaborate on your answer a bit what do you mean by $\text{null}(A)\neq 0$?

Comment: By definition, $\operatorname{null}A=\{\mathbf w\mid A\mathbf w=0\}$. And you areassuming that $\operatorname{null}A$ has, at least, two vectors. So, $\operatorname{null}A\neq\{0\}$, since $\{0\}$ consists of a single vector.

Comment: Right thank you. I thought you might need to use the rank-nullity theorem. Could you show me how if so??? Thank so very much for your help on this!!!

Comment: I did not use the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.